# PDO error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php

I have been trying to learn PDO instead of MySQL when using PHP, i have a bit of code i can't see where the error is:

```
<?php

include('includes/db_connection.php');
include('includes/sessions.php');
include('includes/functions.php');
include('includes/header.php');
include('includes/loginnav.php');

$row = DB::getInstance()->selectOneByField('membership', 'username', $member);

$logged_in_users_id = $row['id'];

$result3 = DB::getInstance()->select('
    SELECT  *
    FROM    `pms`
    WHERE   `sender_id` = :logged_in_users_id
    ORDER   BY `date_added` DESC',
[
    'logged_in_users_id' => $logged_in_users_id
]);

if (count($result3) == 0) {
    stderr('No messages have been sent. (<a href="inbox.php">Inbox</a>)');
}

?>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Sentbox</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-responsive table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Subject</td>
                    <th>Date Sent</td>
                    <th>To User</td>
                    <th>Read (<font color="green">Y</font>&nbsp;/&nbsp;<font color="red">N</font>)</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($result3 as $row) { ?>
                    <?php
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $sendee_id = $row['reciever_id'];
                        $read = $row['read_flag'];
                        $row = DB::getInstance()->selectOneByField('membership', 'id', $sendee_id);
                        $sendee = $row['username'];
                        $sendee_id = $row['id'];
                        $row_2 = DB::getInstance()->selectOneByField('pms', 'reciever_id', $logged_in_users_id, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row_2['subject']) ?></strong></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row_2['date_added']) ?></td>
                        <td><a href="user-details.php?id=<?php echo $sendee_id ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($sendee) ?></td>
                        <td style="color: <?php echo ($read == 'Y')? 'green': 'red' ?>"><strong><?php echo htmlspecialchars($read) ?></strong></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error: "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in" on line 52 which beging on this line:

```
<td><strong><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row_2['subject']) ?></strong></td>
```

I have tried to debug what the error is but i'm stuck at the minute, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is. `$row_2` is an object, but you're trying to access it as an array.

Comment: ..in other words try `$row_2->subject`

Comment: Thanks Mikey! worked great :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$row_2->subject` instead of `$row_2['subject']`

When accessing StdClass objects use ->.

Comment: Thank you to Prax a noob mistake!